# Why does executing this function kill my kernel?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have an old Jupyter notebook that I just fired up. It was written by somebody else and is a bit beyond my current ability (i.e., can't just work around the problem myself).

It's a demonstration of k-means, and this function helps display the points.

```
# helper function that allows us to display data in 2 dimensions and highlights the clusters
def display_cluster(X,km=[],num_clusters=0):
    color = 'brgcmyk'
    alpha = 0.5
    s = 20
    if num_clusters == 0:
        plt.scatter(X[:,0],X[:,1],c = color[0],alpha = alpha,s = s)
    else:
        for i in range(num_clusters):
            plt.scatter(X[km.labels_==i,0],X[km.labels_==i,1],c = color[i],alpha = alpha,s=s)
            plt.scatter(km.cluster_centers_[i][0],km.cluster_centers_[i][1],c = color[i], marker = 'x', s = 100)
```

The next cell runs the function, and it always kills my kernel:

```
angle = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,20, endpoint = False)
X = np.append([np.cos(angle)],[np.sin(angle)],0).transpose()
display_cluster(X)
```

If I comment out the first two lines, it will execute. When I call `display_cluster(X)`, my kernel dies.

How can I salvage this?

Answer (score 0):

You're using a non-ipython kernel. The line that is causing the problem is:

```
# if num_clusters == 0:
#     plt.scatter(X[:,0],X[:,1],c = color[0],alpha = alpha,s = s)
```

This code block uses the `plt.scatter()` function to draw circles for each point in the dataset. If you are using IPython, the issue should be resolved by commenting out these two lines of code and running your notebook again. If you are using a non-IPython kernel, this line throws an error because we have not loaded the matplotlib library in our Python environment and so can't access its functions; but it would be loaded if we ran this cell in an IPython environment (notebook or console). Try that!

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand. I do have `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` in my first cell. I'm running a Python 3 kernel. I can't just comment out the lines you said, because then it breaks the function, which I need to display my plots.

Comment: No worries! I'm not entirely sure why it works for me, but it seems to be that Python is only looking for the `plt` name within the specific namespace that is `matplotlib.pyplot`. You can call the function using just `plt` and it will work. Try that, you should get the same result as before.

Also, I think you're right to be slightly confused by how I can use `plt` when I haven't called it in a `matplotlib.pyplot` way in my script. I've found that if you just type that name and hit `Tab`, the kernel will autocomplete the name for you and then you can call it using the appropriate syntax.